# browse-able hierarchy vs. sitemap

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

The current site navigation is done through a search form. UX wise, I feel it's the best solution we can currently offer our uses. Because this is the case, I have a sitemap that covers all the pages (5Million). Will it improve SEO, if I built a browse-able hierarchy that its sole purpose is only to help spiders?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to SEO a search only website?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/how-to-seo-a-search-only-website)

Comment: @w3d that question doesn't help me as it doesn't consider the site has an sitemap. I'm trying to understand if it makes a difference to the spider to receive the links from a sitemap than through a browse-able hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

At least as far as Google is concerned, the sitemap file will be helping… but not as much as actual links in pages would. It's covered in [this Q&A video with Matt Cutts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi5DGOu1uA0). He's talking about public facing site maps, which I imagine isn't an option for 5 million pages, but the principle is the same: crawlable links on web pages.

I'd definitely consider some sort of "normal" navigation, even if limited. Breadcrumbs would be particularly helpful, especially if you can get them through all pages.